# Primefaces js not working inside p:layout

Tags: javascript, jsf, layout, primefaces

```
    <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
      xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
      xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
      xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">

    <f:view  contentType="text/html">
        <h:head>

            <f:facet name="first">
                <h:outputScript library="primefaces" name="jquery/jquery.js"/>
                <h:outputScript target="head">
                    $ = jQuery;
                </h:outputScript>
            </f:facet>
            <script type="text/javascript">
                function scrollToTop() {
                    $('html, body').animate({scrollTop: 0}, 'slow');
                }
            </script>

        </h:head>

        <h:body id="body">
            <h:form id="form"> 

                <p:layout id="layout" fullPage="true">
                    <p:layoutUnit id="mid" position="center" style="background: #125790; ">
                        <br></br><br></br><br></br><br></br><br></br><br></br>
                        <br></br><br></br><br></br><br></br><br></br><br></br>
                        <br></br><br></br><br></br><br></br><br></br><br></br>
                        <br></br><br></br><br></br><br></br><br></br><br></br>
                        <br></br><br></br><br></br><br></br><br></br><br></br>
                        <br></br><br></br><br></br><br></br><br></br><br></br>
                        <a href="javascript:scrollToTop()">Scroll to top</a>
                    </p:layoutUnit>
                </p:layout>
            </h:form>
        </h:body>
    </f:view>
</html>
```

ScrollTop is not working. What is the problem?

Comment: What does firebug (or something equivalent) say? Any errors we can work with?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because it is not the html or body which has been scrolled, but instead the HTML representation of the content of `<p:layoutUnit position="center">`. The `$("html,body")` selector does not cover that and therefore it does not seem to do anything. If you're familiar with basic HTML and CSS and look closer at the generated HTML output, then you'll understand it.

The right selector is:

```
$(".ui-layout-center .ui-layout-unit-content").animate({scrollTop: 0}, "slow");
```

---

**Unrelated** to the concrete problem, the way how you declared the scripts is unnecessarily clumsy. Just this should do:

```
<h:head>
    <h:outputScript library="primefaces" name="jquery/jquery.js" />
    <h:outputScript>
        function scrollToTop() {
            $(".ui-layout-center .ui-layout-unit-content").animate({scrollTop: 0}, "slow");
        }
    </h:outputScript>
</h:head>
```

Even better, put that function in its own JS file:

```
<h:head>
    <h:outputScript library="primefaces" name="jquery/jquery.js" />
    <h:outputScript name="functions.js" />
</h:head>
```

Further, the usage of `javascript:` pseudoprotocol in `href` is here obtrusive and discouraged. You should put the real href in `href` and make use of `onclick` to enhance it unobtrusively.

```
<p:layoutUnit position="center">
    <div id="top" />
    ...
    <a href="#top" onclick="scrollToTop(); return false;">Scroll to top</a>
</p:layoutUnit>
```

Yet better, add the click event handler during onload in such way that your HTML is free of hardcoded `on*` attributes.

This all also indicates a poor understanding of basic JS. I suggest to learn that as well along with basic HTML and CSS. Ultimately, if you understand HTML/CSS/JS better, you'll automagically also understand JSF much better (it's in the context of this question namely merely a HTML/CSS/JS code generator).